# Ranger user sync with kerberos

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, ambari

I have setup Kerberos following below document
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_Ambari_Security_Guide/content/ch_configuring_amb_hdp_for_kerberos.html

Further, I would like to configure ranger to sync all Kerberos principals to create ACLS. There is an option to sync users from AD but I don't see any option to sync from Kerberos. See options in image below 
[image]
Can anyone please help with options for doing this. Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.   See [ask].

Comment: Which kind of "Kerberos" are you using for authentication -- AD, MIT Kerberos mapped on LDAP, MIT Kerberos standalone? And what do you use for group-level authorization -- Linux groups, LDAP groups, nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want to import, but I assume you have AD and local cluster KDC which are configured with trusted relations and you want all your principles to be represented in Ranger by standalone user accounts. If you have trusted relations configured that means that your entire list of principles would consist of both local KDC and AD and they all would be valid for authentication. But in ranger you work not with the actual Kerberos principles, but with the usernames, which are obtained from **auth_to_local** configuration setting according to the mapping rules specified there.

If you are running LDAP sync, it will pass all matching principles through the collection of rules in this configuration property and will create the end user account with names obtained after execution of these rules. You can check the end results using:

```
hadoop org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName principle@domain.com
```

For local KDC it really does not make sense to pass the principles from KDC through this mapping stage as at the end they all will be mapped to local UNIX accounts. That is why you can just point your **group** and **passwd** files in UNIX sync source and you can assume that all your local Kerberos principles would be represented in the Ranger database with proper user accounts.

You can find some more details about the aspects of Kerberos mappings in this [article](https://oyermolenko.blog/2017/02/11/hadoop-security-overview/)

Comment: Thanks, I don't have AD but only KDC with principals. Also, my use case is to secure Kafka and currently I can't find a way to sync Kerberos principals in ranger unless I create local user on host for each principal. Is that correct way or is there a way to define auth_to_local for Kafka?

Comment: @Mkt281001 The correct way would be to create a separate Unix accounts per each individual group of Kerberos principle in every host. And then you can use Unix sync to keep them up-to-date in your Ranger DB. So in order to Kerberize Kafka you have to - 1) Create Kafka principles in your KDC 2) Create local Kafka account on every node 3) Map principle to local account in auth_to_local 4) Use sync module to import local user to Ranger

Comment: Thanks @Alex that make sense.